# how to get 3rd dimension array in 3d array in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```
int array[3][3][8] = {
    {{3, 4, 5}, {3, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 7}},
    {{1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 5, 7}},
    {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 7}}
};
```

User inputs x,y coordinate and direction, at that location they can only move in 0-7 direction. However, each location can only move towards certain direction. Therefore I am making this array to see if that direction is in that x, y coordinate’s array. After I get the 3rd dimension array (becomes 1d array), I will see if user input direction is in that array.
For example:

```
 {3,4,5} at 1x1 // then check if direction is in this array
```

I tried:

```
 int new_array[8] = array[1][1];
```

Error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

```
 int new_array = array[1][1][]; // {3,4,5}
```

Error: expected primary-expression before ']' token 
So I know this syntax isn't valid, are there other ways to achieve such operation?
To copy the 3rd dimension array into a new array.

Comment: not clear what is the issue. You want copy from your 3d array to some other array? You want to change data from `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` to `[3,4,5]`? What exactly the issue? your first snippet works just fine.

Comment: I was trying to copy that 3rd dimension array out then do if in array with a user input value

Comment: Still unclear. So you set user at {0,0,0} and he inputs something like x=0,y=0, coord=5 meaning we want to change z value at [0][0][5]? Or values inside arrays represent some relation to other array indicies and it's data is some graph? We need some example how do you want to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

    int new_array[8];

    std::copy(std::begin(array[1][1]),
              std::end(array[1][1]),
              new_array);
```

---

Done using `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

// ...

    std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 8>, 3>, 3> array = {{
        {{
            {3,4,5},
            {3,5,7},
            {5,6,7}
        }},
        {{
            {1,3,5},
            {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
            {1,5,7}
        }},
        {{
            {1,2,3},
            {1,3,7},
            {0,1,7}
        }},
    }};

    std::array<int, 8> new_array = array[1][1];

    // the same result but simpler:

    auto new_array = array[1][1];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that’s what I was looking for

Comment: @Mcmx385 You're welcome! You could also take a look at using `std::array`. If often simplifies things like this.

Comment: @Mcmx385 I added using `std::array` as an option. It took me some time to get the braces right I must admit. :-)

Answer (score 0):

there is no way you can get the col or row of an array like that...
if you define a primitive array then you have to navigate the cells and asign the values

```
int main() {
    int test[2][3][2] = {
                            {
                                {1, 2},
                                {3, 4},
                                {5, 6}
                            }, 
                            {
                                {7, 8}, 
                                {9, 10}, 
                                {11, 12}
                            }
                        };
    int z[2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k) {
                z[k] = test[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
    {
        cout << "z[" << k << "] = " << z[k] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Is there another way to define the 3D?